# How can I be certain that a NSString is really an int?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I'm trying to validate that an `NSString` is an `int`. I have the following code to attempt this:

```
if([[NSScanner scannerWithString:stringValue] scanInt:nil]){
//...
}
```

However, if the `stringValue` is `@"1.0something"` this will still return a `YES` boolean to check if my `NSString` is an `int`.

Is there a way to be more accurate than this?

Comment: You could use a regular expression, or you could try to parse to it to a number and catch any exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to convert the `int` back to an `NSString` and see if it matches the original string.

```
NSString *oldStr = ... // your original string
NSString *newStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [oldStr intValue]];
if ([newStr isEqualToString:oldStr]) {
    // the string is a valid int value
}
```

You can also expand your `NSScanner` check and ensure the scanner is at the end after you call `scanInt:`.

```
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:stringValue];
if ([scanner scanInt:nil] && [scanner atEnd]) {
    // valid int string
}
```

Or you can make sure the string only contains the characters 0-9:

```
if ([stringValue rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"] invertedSet]].location == NSNotFound) {
    // valid int
}
```

Or you can use a regular expression.

Comment: This seems like it would work but is a little hacky? Just to be sure is there no method that ios provides to do this? Seems odd.

Answer (score 1):

check like this

```
NSScanner* scan = [NSScanner scannerWithString:stringValue]; 
int val; 
return [scan scanInt:&val] && [scan isAtEnd];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`NSNumberFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/) to determine if the string is a valid number:

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
[formatter numberFromString:@"1.0"]; // returns @(1)
[formatter numberFromString:@"1.0something"]; // returns nil
```

Since partial string validation is not enabled by default, it will reject strings that don't entirely validate as a number.

Comment: The goal is to check for an integer, not an number.